# Workfusion: How to click all hyperlinks within an email, except those links after 'Thanks'?

Tags: rpa, workfusion

I want to click on all links which are present in an email, except those which are not the actual part of the email.

I want to do this by using a loop or something. Eg. If there are 3 links, then traverse For loop 3 times, click on each hyperlink and do something.

How do I do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show some code.

Comment: I've tried saving entire data in a variable using OCR, and then copy that data in a list then traverse `for each element in list`. But, entire data does not get converted to list, and hence I am not able to do so.

I've also tried using OCR to check for keywords like 'Regards' or 'Thanks', until then read all data and put in for each. But this is not able to fulfill my requirements as well

Can you suggest some alternative?

Comment: Why do you use OCR? Can you not read the email as text or HTML?

Comment: Yes. But it gets too lengthy to read the text then in HTML / text. So, trying to read via OCR

Comment: I don't get it. What do you mean lengthy? How do you want to click on text that you use OCR on? Extracting the links from HTML is a matter of a few commands.

Comment: Okay. Then can you please let me know what are those few commands to extract links from HTML?

Answer (score 2):

The steps you need to follow are these:

1. Get mail HTML body
2. Convert HTML to XML
3. Perform XPath to find your links

It can look something like this:

```
<xpath expression="//a[following::*[contains(text(),'Thanks')]]">
    <html-to-xml>
        <!-- your e-mail HTML body -->
    </html-to-xml>
</xpath>
```